# Turning a program - which writes to a file - into a GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

my program works great and next, I want to turn it into a GUI. I have a menu:

```
    System.out.println("Menu: ");
    System.out.println("1) Enter Student Grade(s)");
    System.out.println("2) View Student Grade(s)");
    System.out.println("3) Delete Student Grade(s)");
    System.out.println("4) Exit");
```

I'm not sure how to implement this into a GUI. I could maybe have 4 text fields: First name, Last name, unit and mark. I could have a button to delete, and a button to open the 'GradeEnter.txt' file perhaps. Again, I am not sure how I would implement this into a separate GUI class. Could anyone help or get me started? Thanks

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ExamGrades {
    private static int menu = 0;
    private static String firstName = "";
    private static String firstNameDelete = "";
    private static String lastName = "";
    private static String lastNameDelete = "";
    private static String unit = "";
    private static int examMark = 0;
    private static String entry = "";
    private static String firstCap = "";
    private static String surCap = "";
    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static BufferedWriter bw;
    public static BufferedReader reader;
    public static PrintWriter out;
    public static File deleteRecord;

    public static void setup() {
        reader = null;
        File deleteRecord = new File("GradeEnter.txt");
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(deleteRecord));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.err.println("No file found");
        }
        FileWriter grades = null;
        try {
            grades = new FileWriter("GradeEnter.txt",true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(grades);
        out = new PrintWriter(bw);
    }

    public static void menuActions()
    {
        System.out.println("Menu: ");
        System.out.println("1) Enter Student Grade(s)");
        System.out.println("2) View Student Grade(s)");
        System.out.println("3) Delete Student Grade(s)");
        System.out.println("4) Exit");
        menu = scan.nextInt();
        switch(menu) {
        case 1:
            enterGrades();
            break;
        case 2:
            viewGrades();
            break;
        case 3:
            deleteGrades();
            break;
        case 4:
            exitProgram();
            break;
        default:
            menuActions();
        }
    }

    public static void enterGrades()
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter student first name: ");
        firstName = scan.next(); 

        while(!firstName.matches("[-a-zA-Z]*"))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid first name: ");
            firstName = scan.next(); 
        }
        firstCap = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1);


        System.out.print("Please enter student surname: ");
        lastName = scan.next();

        while(!lastName.matches("[-a-zA-Z]*"))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid surname: ");
            lastName = scan.next();
        }
        surCap = lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + lastName.substring(1);

        System.out.print("Please select Subject Unit: "); 
        unit = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Please enter student mark: ");
        while (!scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid mark: ");
            scan.next();
        }
        examMark = scan.nextInt();

        if (examMark < 40)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
        else if (examMark >= 40 && examMark <= 49)
        {
            System.out.println("3rd");
        }
        else if (examMark >= 50 && examMark <= 59)
        {
            System.out.println("2/2");
        }
        else if (examMark >= 60 && examMark <= 69)
        {
            System.out.println("2/1");
        }
        else if (examMark >= 70 && examMark <= 100)
        {
            System.out.println("1st");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Mark");
        }
        entry = (firstCap + " " + surCap + ", " + unit + ", " + examMark);
        out.println(entry);
        menuActions();
    }
    public static void viewGrades() {
        int i =1;

        String line;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(i + ") " + line);    
                i++; 

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, found IOException when searching for record " + e.getMessage());
        }
        menuActions();
    }
    public static void deleteGrades(){
        int i = 1;
        String line;
        File tempFile = new File("MyTempFile.txt");
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, found IOException when using BufferedWriter " + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Current Entries Stored: ");
        i =1;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(i + ") " + line);    
                i++; 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, found IOException when searching for record to delete " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("To delete, please enter student's First Name: "); 
        firstNameDelete = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Now, please enter student's Surname: ");
        lastNameDelete = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, found IOException when closing closing reader: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(deleteRecord));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No file found");
        }
        String currentLine = "";
        try {
            currentLine = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, found IOException when reading current line " + e.getMessage());
        }

        while(currentLine != null) {
            if(!currentLine.contains(firstNameDelete) && !currentLine.contains(lastNameDelete)) {
                try {
                    writer.write(currentLine);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Error, found IOException when deleting line " + e.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    writer.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Error, found IOException when writing a new line " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            try {
                currentLine = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error, found IOException when reading file " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        System.out.print("if name matches, it will be deleted ");
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.err.println("Error, found IOException when closing reader " + e1.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error, found IOException when closing writer " + e.getMessage());
        }
        deleteRecord.delete();
        tempFile.renameTo(deleteRecord);
        scanner.close();
    }
    public static void exitProgram(){
        System.out.println("Thanks for using 'GradeEnter' ");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the 'GradeEnter' program! ");
        setup();
        menuActions();
        out.close();
        scan.close();
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

EDIT: GradeEnter.txt looks like:

```
Matt Well, Computing, 100
Adam Smith, Computing, 99
```

Above is made up of First Name, Last Name, Course and Mark

Comment: You've mentioned an approach that uses text fields. What happened when you tried that approach?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'm currently unsure how I would navigate through the records as there are multiple entries as you can see from the edited post now showing you what GradeEnter.txt looks like

Comment: Take a look at Notepad and see how a file is opened and saved in a GUI.  The first step is to draw your GUI on one or more pieces of paper to see how you want your GUI to look and function.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Decide on how it should look and work first, and when you run into problems implementing it, ask questions. In any case, you should start by decoupling all "paint & input" code from all "business" code. The paint&input code will be replaced by the GUI. The business code is the only part that will survive.

Comment: Actually, the easiest way to solve this problem would be to hire a programmer. Programmers are very good at this sort of thing!